# Proving $\sin^2A+\sin^2B+\sin^2C-2\cos A \cos B \cos C = 2$.

Tags: trigonometry

I have a question like this.

Let $A, B$ and $C$ be angles of a triangle where $A+B+C=180^\circ$. Prove that $\sin^2A+\sin^2B+\sin^2C-2\cos A \cos B \cos C = 2$.

So, I said to prove that equality it is the same as proving
$\sin^2A+\sin^2B+\sin^2C=2+2\cos A \cos B \cos C $.

After that, I manipulated the LHS by using some formulas and identities until I ended up with the RHS.

But, someone told me that I was wrong because I manipulated both sides to prove that equality. In my opinion, after I moved the part "$-2 \cos A \cos B \cos C$" to the RHS and then worked with the new LHS until I get the LHS is the same as RHS, it is okay. It seems like we work with new question.

What do you guys think? Please share your opinion. Thank you! (I'm sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Probably you forgot to add that $A,B,C$ are internal angles of a triangle. Otherwise the claim is false.

Comment: Your approach sounds fine.

Comment: what the 'someone' told is wrong,ignore him/her

Comment: This is not true if A, B, and C equal $\pi/2$

Comment: @user $A, B, C$ are internal angles of a triangle. $A+B+C=180^\circ$.

Comment: @Moti No, $A, B$, and $C$ all can't equal $\frac{\pi}{2}$ since $A+B+C = 180^\circ$ or $\pi$

Comment: @mathshd You should state this in the question, not in the comment.

Comment: @user Yes, I'm sorry for that.

Comment: The statements $a=b$ and $a+c=b+c$ are equivalent for any real numbers $a,b,c$. 

Anybody who calims the opposite needs to learn  the basics of math.

Answer (score 1):

Note $\cos C= \cos(\pi-A-B)=-\cos(A+B)$. Then
\begin{align}
&\sin^2A+\sin^2B+\sin^2C\\
=& \frac12(1-\cos 2A )+\frac12(1-\cos2B)+(1-\cos^2C )\\
=& 2-\cos(A+B)\cos(A-B) +\cos^2(A+B)\\
 =& 2-\cos(A+B)[\cos(A-B) +\cos(A+B)]\\
 =& 2-\cos(A+B)\cdot2\cos A\cos B\\
 =& 2+2\cos C\cos A\cos B\\
\end{align}

Comment: I don't think the author asked for a proof of the statement.

Comment: @user - you maybe right

Comment: He is right - you just confirmed to the author that his approach was right.